# Ignore embedded quotes in ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, escaping, quotes

I'm not exactly sure what is happening, but the xml file I am writing to has this:

```
This &quot;is&quot; now my String
```

when it should look like this:

```
This "is" now my String
```

Here is the code, except I don't have access to the actual string at compile time. Is there a way to tell the assetName variable to treat embedded quotes as quotes?  Thanks.

```
assetName = 'This "is" now my String'

response.search("property[name=next]").first.andand["value"]  = assetName
```

Comment: You are missing information, like what version of Ruby are you running, and what XML gem you using to generate the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XML, quotes may never appear in attributes, regardless of the style of the quotes used for the attributes. It is likely that your XML library is escaping these quotes for you.